# How to delete deep array in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to delete `"virtualNumber" : "12345"` in the following document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("50a9db5bdc7a04df06000005"),
"billingInfo" : null,
"date" : "dsfdsfsdfsd",
"description" : "sdfsdff",
"pbx" : {
  "_id" : ObjectId("50a9db5bdc7a04df06000006"),
  "did" : {
    "1234567890" : {
      "inventoryId" : "509df7547e84b25e18000001",
      "didcountry" : "india",
      "didState" : "bangalore",
      "routeType" : "CallForward",
      "didNumber" : "1234567890",
      "didVirtualNumbers" : [
        {
          "virtualNumber" : "12345"
        },
        {
          "virtualNumber" : "56789"
        }
      ],
      "id" : ObjectId("50a9db9acdfb4f9217000002")
    }
  },
},
```

I am using node.js, so I constructed a query in JavaScript:

```
var query = {_id: ObjectId("50a9db5bdc7a04df06000005")};

var obj = {};
obj["pbx.did.1234567890.didVirtualNumbers.virtualNumber"]=12345;
//problem
collection.update(query,{$pull:obj});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to match the array element like:

```
{"$pull": {"pbx.did.7259591220.didVirtualNumbers": {"virtualNumber": "12345"}}}
```

So you should change your code to:

```
obj["pbx.did.7259591220.didVirtualNumbers"]={"virtualNumber": "12345"};
```

Comment: thanks but its not working, query is                                                                                  { '$pull': { 'pbx.did.7259591220.didVirtualNumbers': { virtualNumber: '12345' } } }

Comment: When I save the document in your question into "objects" collection in my db, I can remove the virtualNumber "12345" from the document using query `db.objects.update({"_id" : ObjectId("50a9db5bdc7a04df06000005")}, {"$pull": {"pbx.did.7259591220.didVirtualNumbers": {"virtualNumber": "12345"}}})`. After this query, the document contains only the other virtualNumber "56789".

Comment: Are you trying to run this in the Mongo console or as part of you application? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: You have your code inside a db.collection call, right? Have you double checked that you have collection names etc. right?

Comment: oh my god, spelling mistake in collection name..very sorry for troubling, thanks a lot it working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull

It mentions the pull field should be an array.